Migrating from monolithic file.upload to sequential/asynchronous files.getUploadURLExternal and files.completeUploadExternal
I scratched my head for hours trying to figure out the way to migrate after receiving the email from Slack's team of the future deprecation of file.upload. The message is the same as https://api.slack.com/changelog/2024-04-a-better-way-to-upload-files-is-here-to-stay
Wrote this, all is successful, but no image uploaded in the channel:
#!/bin/bash

length=$(wc -c < /tmp/img.png)

curl \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer XXX" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" \
    -d "filename=charts" \
    -d "length=$length" \
    https://slack.com/api/files.getUploadURLExternal > /tmp/slack.json

upload_url=$(jq -r '.upload_url' /tmp/slack.json)
img_id=$(jq -r '.file_id' /tmp/slack.json)

curl \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer XXX" \
    -d "file=@/tmp/img.png" \
    $upload_url

curl \
    https://slack.com/api/files.completeUploadExternal \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer XXX" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
    -d @/dev/stdin << EOF | jq .
    {
        "files": [
            {
                "id": "$img_id",
                "title": "charts",
            }
         ],
         "channel_id": "XYZ",
         "initial_comment": "this is a test"
    } 
EOF

The output:
{
  "ok": true,
  "files": [
    {
      "id": "XXXXX",
      "created": 1727014056,
      "timestamp": 1727014056,
      "name": "charts",
      "title": "charts",
      "mimetype": "",
      "filetype": "",
      "pretty_type": "",
      "user": "XXXXXX",
      "user_team": "XXXXXX",
      "editable": false,
      "size": 5935,
      "mode": "hosted",
      "is_external": false,
      "external_type": "",
      "is_public": false,
      "public_url_shared": false,
      "display_as_bot": false,
      "username": "",
      "url_private": "https://files.slack.com/files-pri/XXXX/charts",
      "url_private_download": "https://files.slack.com/files-pri/XXXX/download/charts",
      "media_display_type": "unknown",
      "permalink": "https://etc-onlyview.slack.com/files/XXXX/charts",
      "permalink_public": "https://slack-files.com/XXXX",
      "comments_count": 0,
      "is_starred": false,
      "shares": {},
      "channels": [],
      "groups": [],
      "ims": [],
      "has_more_shares": false,
      "has_rich_preview": false,
      "file_access": "visible"
    }
  ]
}

If I try to open URLs in a logged in browser, I get error: There was a problem when trying to open this link We're not quite sure what went wrong. You can go back, or try looking on our Help Center if you need a hand.
Or some other URLs, I get error redirected you too many times.
Looks like a under construction project.

unrelated to your problem, and really just a nit, but stat "%s" will probably be much more efficient at getting the file size. For a one-off, no biggie, as a habit that you take with you into large data processing projects (along with others), could turn into percentages of lost time.
